# Is there any general purpose perl module with helpers for web applications?

Tags: perl, html-helper

Is there a general purpose Perl Module with helpers for web development? Like form-builders, url helper, etc?

Based on my searches, I couldn't find anything. I'm already using Mason, but do not want to define my helpers as components from scratch.

Comment: I believe the helpers will be found in framework-specific plugins; I don't know what's out there for Mason, but if you identified some specific tasks I bet you'd get better answers.

Comment: Helper functions for generating tables, form-builders, file uploads, etc if it makes sense?

Comment: err, isn't a lot of that what Mason is for?

Comment: Well, yes, but I would have to define my own helpers, put them in some component, and then use them as required. If there is already code out there that takes an array ref and converts it to a table, and takes a hash ref and converts it to a form, I don't need to write/maintain it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is open-ended and it sounds like you want to eat your framework and have it. Still, here are some starting points.

#### Form helpers

In *approximately* the order of preference:

- [HTML::FormHandler](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aFormHandler)
- [HTML::FormFu](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aFormFu)
- [Rose::HTML::Objects](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Rose%3a%3aHTML%3a%3aObjects)
- [CGI::FormBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI%3a%3aFormBuilder) (I think this is abandoned)

#### URL helpers

- [URI](http://ttp://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI)
- [URI::QueryParam](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aQueryParam)
- [URI::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aEscape)
- [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path%3a%3aClass)

[Mojolicious](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojolicious) has some discrete pieces that might be worth looking at too. Even if you don't use a framework, you should look at them and the choices they make for plugins and helpers.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, more than you can shake a stick at.

The [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/~markstos/CGI.pm-3.55/lib/CGI.pm) module includes support for building forms, and other formatting things, if you want something very basic/low-level.

If you want more of a framework, there are dozens or more.  pokey909's answer is a good place to start if that's your goal.

And there are hundreds or more special-use modules related to specific aspects of web applications.  Search [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) for these more specific ones.

Answer (score 1):

I cant see how you couldnt find anything else. Just google for "perl web framework".

There a quite a few, have a look here:
https://www.socialtext.net/perl5/web_frameworks

Comment: Not looking for an entire web framework... just helpers. I have my routing, models, controllers, etc set up.